# How to keep transaction generating time down?

Tags: transactions, wallet, payment

I have a wallet for a service that's getting bloated, and whenever I want to send transactions they notably get slow. How do I prevent stuff like this? Can I just send all the funds to an address to merge the unspent inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always send whatever you have in your wallet to another address in the same wallet.
Depending on the size of the transaction you might have to pay a larger fee than normal.